# In Python, how to sort a dict inside a dict by a key within the inner dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data set in key/value form:

```
setlist = {{'135350258120342034': {'title':'The Matrix'}
          {'235350258120342034': {'title':'The Godfather'}
          {'335350258120342034': {'title':'Atonement'}
          }
```

How can I sort setlist by the value of 'key' which is a dict within a dict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> sorted(setlist.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]['title'])
[('335350258120342034', {'title': 'Atonement'}), ('235350258120342034', {'title': 'The Godfather'}), ('135350258120342034', {'title': 'The Matrix'})]
```

Comment: Note that you can't really sort the setlist, because it's a dict. But you can produce a sorted list of key/value pairs, which is what this code does.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, dicts can't be sorted.

What you can do is move your key for the outer dict into the inner dicts, then stick them in a list and use a custom function with .sort()

Comment: +1 for pointing out the nature of dicts, but there are simpler ways to get the desired effect, as shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the list in a sorted order you want something like:

```
for key, value in sorted(setlist.items(), key = lambda x: x[-1]['title']):
   pass
```